# MySQL SELECT WHERE based on TIME

Tags: mysql

I've a query with a lot of `WHERE` conditions, but one of them needs to be dynamic. I need that one `WHERE` is applied only if the actual time is between 09:00 and 18:00. I.e.:

```
SELECT x,y from z WHERE
x = 'hello'
{ if time between 09:00 and 18:00 then }
AND y = 'world'
{ end if }
```

How to apply such a where condition?

Many thanks, Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the conditions like this:

```
SELECT x, y 
FROM z 
WHERE x = 'hello'
  AND (time NOT BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:00' OR y = 'world')
```

This way the condition `y = 'world'` will affect the result only if `time BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:00'` is `true`.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll check it but seems that it's what I'm searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `HOUR(CURRENT_TIME())` which gives you current hour.

```
... WHERE HOUR(CURRENT_TIME()) > 9 AND HOUR(CURRENT_TIME()) < 18 ...
```